# How do I use the output of a node.js (or alike) program as a unix command line input?

Tags: unix, command-line

I have a simple node js program named `test_cmd.js`. I want to run this program through a unix shell, and use the output of the program to execute a unix command.

`test_cmd.js` can simply be:

```
console.log('echo "hello, world!"');
```

Output:

```
>> pi@raspberrypi ~/ $ node test_cmd.js
>> echo "hello, world!" # I want the unix shell I just ran this program in to run this output as a command, but how?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pipe it as stdin to the shell:

```
$ node test_cmd.js | bash
hello, world!
```